# Finding Top-K records in a dataset

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In attempt to learn Hadoop, I am practicing unsolved programming questions from the book "Hadoop in Action"

**Dataset Sample:**

> 3070801,1963,1096,,"BE","",,1,,269,6,69,,1,,0,,,,,,,
>   3070802,1963,1096,,"US","TX",,1,,2,6,63,,0,,,,,,,,,
>   3070803,1963,1096,,"US","IL",,1,,2,6,63,,9,,0.3704,,,,,,,
>   3070804,1963,1096,,"US","OH",,1,,2,6,63,,3,,0.6667,,,,,,,
>   3070805,1963,1096,,"US","CA",,1,,2,6,63,,1,,0,,,,,,,
>   3070806,1963,1096,,"US","PA",,1,,2,6,63,,0,,,,,,,,,
>   3070807,1963,1096,,"US","OH",,1,,623,3,39,,3,,0.4444,,,,,,,
>   3070808,1963,1096,,"US","IA",,1,,623,3,39,,4,,0.375,,,,,,,
>   3070809,1963,1096,,"US","AZ",,1,,4,6,65,,0,,,,,,,,,
>   3070810,1963,1096,,"US","IL",,1,,4,6,65,,3,,0.4444,,,,,,,

**Map Function**

```
public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Text, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
        private int maxClaimCount = 0;
        private Text record = new Text();

        public void map(Text key, Text value, OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            String claim = value.toString().split(",")[7];
            //if (!claim.isEmpty() && claim.matches("\\d")) {
            if (!claim.isEmpty()) {
                int claimCount = Integer.parseInt(claim);
                if (claimCount > maxClaimCount) {
                    maxClaimCount = claimCount;
                    record = value;
                    output.collect(new IntWritable(claimCount), value);
                }
//              output.collect(new IntWritable(claimCount), value);
            }
        }

    }
```

**Reduce Function**

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            output.collect(key, values.next()); 
    }
}
```

**Command to Run:**

```
hadoop jar ~/Desktop/wc.jar com/hadoop/patent/TopKRecords -Dmapred.map.tasks=7 ~/input  ~/output
```

**Requirement:**
- Based on the ninth column value, find the top-K records(say 7) from dataset

**Question:**
- Since just 7 top records are needed I run seven map tasks and make sure that I get the highest number record as `maxClaimCount` and `record`
- I do not know how to collect just the maximum record so that each map emits just one output

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an updated answer. All comments are not applicable to it as they are based on original (incorrect) answer.

---

Mapper should only output

```
output.collect(new IntWritable(claimCount), value);
```

without any comparison. Result will be sorted based on claim count and passed to reducer.

In Reducer use some priority queue to pick up top 7 results.

Comment: Since there is just one reduce and think if the map output emits the results that is not enough to fit in a memory, sotring the results might not happen in this case, right?

Comment: Each map will emit only 7 records. I think you should be fine.

Comment: How can we be so sure, there are 7 map tasks they might get random chunks of data so each split might emit more than 7 records. With current run I am getting 264 records which is much more than 49 records

Comment: You can use priority queue to store max 7 records or something like that.

Comment: You will pick up top 7 in each chunk. Once you bring them together you are guaranteed to have top 7 out of entire data set among them.

Comment: Okay, not something that at Hadoop level we can specify. i'll try this one out

Comment: Suppose that you have 1000GB of data. You use 100 mappers, each handling 10GB of data and outputting may be 1KB of data. So reducer will handle 100KB of data.

Comment: Okay, quick Question, in terms of code, at what time I would say collect(key, heapObject). seems like map function will be called whenever we have input and we can't collect the heapObject on each map return

Comment: You brought up interesting question. You indeed can only output records when you know for sure that it's one of top 7 records (or top one as in your code). You can only do it when end of input is reached, not when you process each record.

Comment: Yes, so the question comes up when do we know that end of map input is reached. I don't know answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeMap, which stores the key in a sorted manner. Mapper would be

```
public Mapper() {
   TreeMap<String, String> set = new TreeMap<String, String>();
   Void map(object key, Text value){
     Set.put("get key", value);
     If(set.size > 7) {
        Set.removeFirst()
     }

   }

Public void cleanup(){
  While(Entry<string, string> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Conetext.write(entry.key, entry.value);
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use top k design patterns for more details refer the below blog
[Findin Top K records in Mapreduce](https://hadooptechblogs.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/finding-top-k-records-using-map-reduce/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide 
the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.